# Nested RadGrid Wrong Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik, radgrid

I am using Asp.net C# Telerik NestedGrid. When I press first row to expand I get correct results but when I press second row I get the results of first row for some reason I cant get the new values. 
What I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? 
Do I need to make something like :
 `protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)`?

in aspx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" GroupPanelPosition="Top"  Skin="Outlook" Visible="False" AllowPaging="True" >
     <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientDataKeyNames="DocHandle" PageSize="20"   >
       <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocDescr"  HeaderText="DocDescr" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocDescr"/>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocHandle" HeaderText="DocHandle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocHandle" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CreationDate" HeaderText="CreationDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CreationDate" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
       </Columns>
         <NestedViewSettings DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
         <ParentTableRelation>
        <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="DocHandle" MasterKeyField="DocHandle" />
      </ParentTableRelation>
       </NestedViewSettings>
        <NestedViewTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="NestedViewPanel" runat="server" CssClass="viewWrap">
        <div class="contactWrap">
          <fieldset style="padding: 10px;">
            <legend style="padding: 5px;"><b>Detail info for Document: <%#Eval("DocHandle") %></b>
            </legend>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 Document Description:
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" Text='<%#Bind("DocDescr") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                 Creation Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="ownerLabel" Text='<%#Bind("CreationDate", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                 Created By:
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="createdbyLabel" Text='<%#Bind("CreatedBy") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                   </NestedViewTemplate>
       </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following

```
>     <NestedViewSettings DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
>              <ParentTableRelation>
>             <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="DocHandle" MasterKeyField="DocHandle" />
>           </ParentTableRelation>
</NestedViewSettings>
```

from your code and it should be ok.